# limits of DisplayForm integral get swapped when copying, but only visually

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, wolfram-cloud, display

I tried doing the following today (Dec 28, 2022) in my cloud notebook (running on Firefox 102.5.0esr on Debian 11):

`Integrate[Sin[x]/x,{x,0,Infinity}]//Hold`

and the result is fine. However, when I select the output and get a popup saying "copied", then when I do ctrl-v to paste, the limits of the integral are swapped: i.e. it's now inf to 0, not 0 to inf.

Further, when I delete the `Hold[` part and then shift-enter to evaluate, it prints pi/2, which is the value of the integral from 0 to inf (my original intent).

So what seems to be going on here is that the pasted DisplayForm graphically has the limits swapped, but has the actual correct value (without limits swapped).

What's going on here?

EDIT: same exact behavior appears on macOS 13.1 with 108.0.1. Have ublock origin and dark reader extensions on Firefox for both macOS and linux.

See screenshot of this behavior on linux:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I reported this to Wolfram Support and indeed got an email from them claiming that this is a bug, and that they will work on this.